# Google Sign in not working and not showing any error in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My google sign in is not working and not showing any error.
also I use react routing...bt a lot of I'm trying to use google login method but it's not working...[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvA0r.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import useAuth from "../../Hooks/useAuth";

import './Login.css'




const Login = () => {
const {signInUsingGoogle} = useAuth()
 return (
     <div className='my-5'>
         <div className="d-grid mb-2 justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
         <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
         <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRr6IrIk4SLn7-Uc5g0gE28o3vL1XBYjXgLEzFglZn4SABYEzDppXBSEhtma8d2CA7C_d4&usqp=CAU" width='200px' />
         <Card.Body>
         <button 
         onClick={signInUsingGoogle}
         className="btn btn-google btn-login text-uppercase fw-bold btn-outline-danger"
         type="submit"
       >
       <i className="fab fa-google"></i> Sign in with Google
       </button>
         </Card.Body>
       </Card>
         </div>

         
     </div>
 );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: You should post your code for `useAuth` hook

Answer (score 0):

and

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleAuthProvider,signInWithPopup, getAuth,onAuthStateChanged, signOut  } from "firebase/auth";
import initializeConfig from '../Firebase/Firebase.init';








initializeConfig();
const useFirebase = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const auth = getAuth();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    const signInUsingGoogle = () => {
        console.log('signing in...');
      return  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
           console.log('signing in...');
            setUser(result.user);
        })
}

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribed = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(user)
            }
            else {
                setUser({})
            }
        });
        return () => unsubscribed;
    },[])
    
    
    const logOut = () => {
        signOut(auth)
            .then(() => {
            
        })
    }

    return (
        user,
        signInUsingGoogle,
        logOut
    );
};

export default useFirebase;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nothing solved...